# How to properly subclass an UserControl in this way?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, user-controls

> SCENARIO

I have a subclassed NumericDown like this:

```
Public Class MyNumericUpDown : Inherits NumericUpDown

  ' More code here that does not matter...

End Class
```

I would like to compile it as an `UserControl` of a **WindowsForms Control Library** project to have the beneffit of the UserControl's property grid when debugging the project.

> PROBLEM

I can't find the way to compile my NumericDown as I want without breaking the auto-generated `Usercontrol` class of the **WindowsForms Control Library** project, this means, breaking the property grid feature and after compiling the project having a final exception message saying me that my dll: `doesn't contain any UserControl types` (but really there is and I can add it into the VS control toolbox).

> QUESTION

In C# or VB, how I can properly white an **WindowsForms Control Library** project to show only my custom NumericDown without loosing the property grid feature?

I hope you could understand what I want.

I'll try to say it in other words: I only would like to test my NumericUpDown in the property grid, not the usercontrol generated by default by the **WindowsForms Control Library** project.

It should be an "unit" when adding the dll into the VisualStudio control toolbox but instead that I get two separated controls.

> CODE:

I don't have anything better to show because I can't find info to start doing this.

```
Public Class UserControl1 : Inherits UserControl

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        ' This is not what I want, 
        ' or at least I think it shouldn't be done as normally like this, 
        ' I only want to use and see my custom NumericUpDown on the property grid, 
        ' not depending on any UserControl ControllCollection.
        Me.Controls.Add(New MyNumericUpDown)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: There is no need to add your subclassed control to a WF Control Lib project - they can work perfectly well without the overhead of a UserControl.  Net is "auto generating" a UC because of the project type; you are apparently adding your NUD onto a Usercontrol.  Create a "Class Lib" project and add your subclassed control along with some WinForms references.  Many, many, many subclassed controls work very well without the "benefit" of a UserControl.  I am not sure what "property grid" you are talking about though - tge std properties window?

Comment: I know how to compile a control doing it in the way that you've said without depending on an UC. What I try to ask is: when you compile and run an user control (WF Control Lib project) VisualStudio displays a control's property grid at run time to test the control properties, that is what I want to have with my custom control that does not inherits from an UC in a WF Control Lib project, in case of that is possibly to do I don't know, thanks for comment.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what property grid (at runtime) you are talking about.

Comment: @Plutonix Just create a new empty WF Control lib usercontrol project and press the start button to compile and run it, then VisualStudio will display you a test container with the user control and a control's property grid: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Then, that Is what I would like to have with my custom "numericupdown" usercontrol that does not inherits from an usercontrol type, or to make the needed modifications to inherit from it... I don't know how to.

Comment: Oh, the TestContainer - I think that works for UserControls only because the controls on it are able to be instanced (a UC is sort of a mini form) .  A test project with a form is the equivalent for a normal control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test application that is shipped with Visual Studio will only search for controls derived from [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol(v=vs.90).aspx). If you want it to be able to view/test other types then you need to create a custom application.

The following code is just a *proof of concept*. The easiest way to implement a full working application is to simply drop the `UserControlTestContainer.exe` onto a decompiler like reflector and copy the code.

1. Create a custom windows forms application and name it `UserControlTestContainer`.
2. Create a shared sub main.
3. Uncheck `enable application framework` and set the `startup object` to `sub main`.
4. When your code looks like mine, build.

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New(Optional ByVal args As String() = Nothing)
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me.args = New Label With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill, .Text = If((args Is Nothing), "(null)", String.Join(Environment.NewLine, args))}
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.args)
    End Sub

    <STAThread()>
    Public Shared Sub Main(Optional ByVal args As String() = Nothing)
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.Run(New Form1(args))
    End Sub

    Private args As Label

End Class
```

5. Replace the default `UserControlTestContainer.exe` located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio {version}\Common7\IDE` with your custom `UserControlTestContainer.exe`.
6. Back in the windows forms control library create a custom control derived from `Control` and hit run.

[image: Custom UserControl Test Container]